# React Router displays the contents of a path permanently on the home page despite routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently using React Router to align my navigation, however one problem remains constant: for example, when I set the "AddFavorites" component to the path "/favorites", the content of the component is still displayed on the path "/". What is the reason for this and how can I change it?

My App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Random from "./components/Random";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MappedCharacters from "./components/MappedCharacters";
import AddFavorites from "./components/AddFavorites";
import SearchBox from "./components/Searchbox";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate,  } from "react-router-dom";

const URL = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character';

function App() {

  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState([])


  async function fetchCharacters() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL);
      const result = await response.json() 
      setCharacters(result.results);
      setHasError(false);
    }
    catch(error) {
    setHasError(true);
    console.error(error);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => { 
    fetchCharacters();
  }, []);

  const addFavoriteCharacter = (character) => {
    const newFavoriteList = [...favorites, character];
    setFavorites(newFavoriteList);
  }

  return (
  <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <SearchBox searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
      <Routes>
      <Route
  exact path="/"
  element={(
    <>
      {characters.map((character) => (
        <MappedCharacters
          key={character.id} 
          name={character.name}
          gender={character.gender}
          status={character.status}
          species={character.species}
          image={character.image}
          favoriteComponent={AddFavorites}
          handleFavoritesClick={addFavoriteCharacter}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  )}
/>

<Route exact path="/favorites" element={<AddFavorites />} />

<Route
  exact path="/random"
  element={(
    <>
      <Random />
    </>
  )}
/>
<Route path="*" element={<h1>Page does not exist.</h1>} />
</Routes>
     <Navbar />
  </div>
  )
}



export default App;
```

My index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And my AddFavorites Component:

```
import React from 'react'


const AddFavorites = (props) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={props.handleFavoritesClick}>
    <span>
        <h2>Your Favorits are listed below</h2>
        </span>
        

    </div>
  )
}
export default AddFavorites
```

Comment: In react-router V6, `exact` prop is removed, and it is default behavior now as same keeping `exact` in `V5` ... can you reproduce the issue in a sandbox as it works for me [here in a basic e.g.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jpzpye?file=src/App.tsx)

Comment: Can you elaborate how the exact keyword is related to the problem? if I remove it in the project, then the routing still does not work correctly and all content is still displayed on the "/".  @KcH

Comment: I didn't say it works just by removing it, just a point I would want to mention 

Comment: that's nice of you but i'm basically looking for something else here. so answers without context confuse rather than help. :D

Comment: You are right so I have put it as a comment 

Comment: In RRDv6 route are now ***always*** exactly matched, the `exact` prop was removed from the API, passing it will do nothing and prop will be ignored. Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue as you describe that we could inspect live? From what I see of the code if the URL path is `"/favorites"` then the `path="/"` route won't be matched and that array of characters won't be rendered.